# Find sequences of sequential numbers in list and its start and end indexes

Tags: python, list, range

So I have a list with some values e.g.:

```
timeSum = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,3]
```

and I need to get boundaries of intervals containing max value.

So I create a list with indices of max value:

```py
maxTime = [i for i, j in enumerate(timeSum) if j == max(timeSum)]
```

which gives me: `[6,7,8,10]`.

Now as I understand I need to find sequences of sequential numbers' boundaries to get output like: `6:8`, `10`
but I am not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: Why does `6:8` an arithmetic progression? Wouldn't that be `0:8`? or `4:6`? Do you need to find sequences of sequential numbers in `maxTime`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes, I basicaly need to find start and end indexes of sequences of sequential numbers in maxTime

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I'm new to python, so for now on I have no idea how it should be done so I'm rapidly reading some language docs to figure it out asap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. This basically creates sublists of the sequences and when the sequence is broken, it adds it to the result.

```py
end_res = []
cur_seq = [maxTime[0]]
for num in maxTime[1:]:
    if num == cur_seq[-1] + 1:
        cur_seq.append(num)
    else:
        end_res.append(cur_seq)
        cur_seq = [num]
end_res.append(cur_seq)
```

Depending on how exactly you want to use the result, this simply prints it like your example:

```py
print(end_res)
for res in end_res:
    if len(res) > 1:
        print(res[0], ':', res[-1], sep='')
    else:
        print(res[0])
```

On the `maxTime` list you gave `[6, 7, 8, 10]`, this gives:

```
[[6, 7, 8], [10]]
6:8
10
```

Comment: Great thanks, man. It is exactly what I was looking for. I almost done it by that point, but got stuck on '10' with an error. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I guess I solved the problem. Please take a look at the below codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

timeSum = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,3]

maxTime = [i for i, j in enumerate(timeSum) if j == max(timeSum)]

is_range = []
not_range = []

for i in range(len(maxTime)):
    try:
        if maxTime[i + 1] - maxTime[i] == 1:
            is_range.append(f"{maxTime[i]}:{maxTime[i + 1]}")
    except:
        if str(maxTime[i]) not in "".join(is_range):
            not_range.append(maxTime[i])


def f(arg):
    for i in range(len(arg)):
        try:
            split1 = arg[i].split(":")
            split2 = arg[i + 1].split(":")
            if split1[-1] == split2[0]:
                arg[i] = arg[i].replace(split1[-1], split2[-1])
                arg.pop(i + 1)
        except:
            pass
    for i in range(len(arg)):
        try:
            split1 = arg[i].split(":")
            split2 = arg[i + 1].split(":")
            if split1[-1] == split2[0]:
                return f(arg)
            else:
                return arg
        except:
            return arg


new_list = f(is_range)
new_list.extend(not_range)

print(new_list)
```

**Output1:**

```
['6:8', 10]
```

If the list is like below,

```
timeSum = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,2,3,3,3]
```

**Output2:**

```
['6:8', '10:12']
```

If the list is like below,

```
timeSum = [0,0,0,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,3,3,3,3]
```

The output would be like:

**Output3:**

```
['6:9', '11:14']
```

Comment: I forgot to add `return arg` in line 39. Now it works as expected.